# Web Deploy Failed Publish

Tags: visual-studio-2017, iis-8, webdeploy

While I publish in VS its filed with message "Publish Failed".

the Output:

> Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to https:// -myStite-...
>    D:\VisualStudio\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4292,5): Error : Web deployment task failed. ((30/10/2017 08:19:07) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)
>
> (30/10/2017 08:19:07) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
>    Value cannot be null.
>      at System.Version.Parse(String input)
>      at System.Version..ctor(String version)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgentWorkerRequest.get_MaximumSupportedVersion()
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleClientServerVersionMismatch(DeploymentAgentWorkerRequest workerRequest)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequestWorker(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequest(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.BeginProcessRequest(DeploymentAgentWorkerRequest workerRequest, AsyncCallback callback, Object extraData)
>    Publish failed to deploy.
>
> ========= Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>   ========= Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

in the EventViwer on the server, this exception:

> User: -my user-
>   Client IP: 10.0.0.138
>   Content-Type: 
>   Version: 9.0.0.0
>   MSDeploy.VersionMin: 
>   MSDeploy.VersionMax: 
>   MSDeploy.Method: 
>   MSDeploy.RequestId: 
>   MSDeploy.RequestCulture: 
>   MSDeploy.RequestUICulture: 
>   ServerVersion: 9.0.1955.0
>   A tracing deployment agent exception occurred that was propagated to the client. Request ID ''. Request Timestamp: '30/10/2017 08:02:11'. Error Details:
>   System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: input
>      at System.Version.Parse(String input)
>      at System.Version..ctor(String version)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgentWorkerRequest.get_MaximumSupportedVersion()
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleClientServerVersionMismatch(DeploymentAgentWorkerRequest workerRequest)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequestWorker(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequest(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)

In the past he worked very well (same saved configuration), and now it fails sometimes.

Comment: also tell what you have tried?

Comment: Well, the error seems to tell you that it is missing a Maximum value for the Version Max. In the Deployment, it's empty. Maybe edit the deployment settings to include a value for: MSDeploy.VersionMax

Comment: Ensure you can hit the endpoint https:// -myStite-...

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem and finally solved it after hours of experimenting.  The problem was being caused by my ISP blocking/interfering with just that type of traffic.  Everything else seemed to work on the ISP, but not publishing my website from Visual Studio (MsDeploy).  Fortunately I have other ISPs providing broadband at my home so I was able to connect to a different ISP immediately and then publish successfully.

The problem occurred on the mobile broadband service provider Three.co.uk.  Other broadband providers that I tried have not had this problem.

It was the following discussion (I translated it from Chinese) which made me realise that my ISP was causing the issue.
https://t.codebug.vip/questions-453963.htm
There is post there from someone with the exact same problem, who has a web server behind CloudFlare and that is what was causing the problem for them.  I am guessing that CloudFlare was put there by their ISP.

I also found another message by someone who also tracked the problem down to their ISP:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7b345fc9-5e3d-4015-99a9-26746ca3d84f/socket-error-10054-when-deploying-web-app-to-azure-via-visual-studio?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview
Running the publish from behind a VPN has solved the issue for them.

So just try publishing via a different ISP or from behind a VPN.  If you only have one fixed line broadband provider, then perhaps try tethering to your phone's broadband provider and publish over that connection.

Comment: This was my problem. Had to disable Cisco Umbrella service and the publish worked fine.